# Universal memoization decorator

Tags: python, python-2.x, meta-programming, memoization, higher-order-functions

I've just written a simple caching / memoization python decorator. It's purpose is to cache what the function returns for all the arguments combinations it's been ever invoked with.

So, if, say, we had a function `my_function(a, b=2, c=3)` invoked once with `my_function(1, 2, c=3)`, the results should be then cached whenever I call it with `my_function(1, 2, 3)` or `my_function(1, c=3, b=2)` or `my_function(c=3, b=2, a=1)`.

Is what's below a good approach and could it be somehow improved?

```
import functools                                                                
import pickle                                                                   


def memoize_all(func):                                                          
    """                                                                         
    This is a caching decorator. It caches the function results for             
    all the arguments combinations, so use it with care. It does not matter      whether the arguments    
    are passed as keywords or not.                                              
    """                                                                         
    cache = {}                                                                  

    @functools.wraps(func)                                                      
    def cached(*args, **kwargs):                                                
        arg_names = func.func_code.co_varnames                                   
        arg_dict = {}                                                           
        for i, arg in enumerate(args):                                          
            arg_dict[arg_names[i]] = args[i]                                     
        arg_dict.update(**kwargs)                                               
        key = pickle.dumps(arg_dict)                                            
        if key not in cache:                                                    
            cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)                                  
        return cache[key]                                                       
    return cached
```

Comment: As a side-note, Python3.3's [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) does this, and [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11815873/321973) lists some 2.7 alternatives / backports

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what's up with the spacing in the docstring, but fix it.

Your `memoize_all` doesn't work with everything:

```
memoize_all(int)(1)
#>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
#>>>   ...
#>>> AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute 'func_code'
```

I suppose this doesn't bother you much, but it irks me ;).

Consider

```
for i, arg in enumerate(args):
    arg_dict[arg_names[i]] = args[i]
```

There's no point doing `args[i]`; it's just `arg`. Further, one should do

```
for i, (name, arg) in enumerate(zip(arg_names, args)):
    arg_dict[name] = arg
```

But then one can just do

```
arg_dict = dict(zip(arg_names, args))
```

You could even use

```
arg_dict = dict(zip(arg_names, args), **kwargs)
```

You try and save this with

```
key = pickle.dumps(arg_dict)
```

I'm not at all fond of this method. `pickle` is a bit fragile and more complicated than I would expect. I would personally do something like

```
key = frozenset(arg_dict.items())
```

If you skip generating `arg_dict`, this is

```
key = frozenset(kwargs.items()) | frozenset(zip(arg_names, args))
```

This does prevent accepting mutable arguments, but it's normally best to enforce purity before caching arguments anyway.

You then have just

```
def cached(*args, **kwargs):
    arg_names = func.func_code.co_varnames
    key = frozenset(kwargs.items()) | frozenset(zip(arg_names, args))

    if key not in cache:
        cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
    return cache[key]
```

Note that in Python 3, this would be better with a signature object:

```
import functools
from inspect import signature

def memoize_all(func):
    """
    This is a caching decorator. It caches the function results for
    all the arguments combinations, so use it with care. It does not
    matter whether the arguments are passed as keywords or not.
    """
    cache = {}
    func_sig = signature(func)

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def cached(*args, **kwargs):
        bound = func_sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        key = frozenset(bound.arguments.items())

        if key not in cache:
            cache[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[key]
    return cached
```

Comment: Thank you! My way of building of arg_dict was totally screwed compared to yours.
And, actually, whereas I realize the mutable type as a default argument should not happen, why passing the list as a function argument would be against purity in this case?

Comment: If I understand the question, it's because `{'x': some_unhashable_object}` isn't hashable.

Comment: Right, but my point is why would one enforce the use of only hashable objects as function arguments (which needs to happen to use frozenset)? I mean do you consider using unhashable objects as function arguments as not "pure"?

Comment: @rroszkowiak It's not an inherent thing, it's just that sans the use of globals, having immutable inputs requires a pure function.